# Update an array of objects with new incremental object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the below array of objects. if i do a console.log, i see this

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
     name: "Rick"
     Contact: "Yes"
1:Object
     name:"Anjie"
     Contact:"No"
2:Object
     name:"dillan"
     Contact:"Maybe"
```

I want the above array of object to be updated like this.

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0:Object
     name: "Rick"
     Contact: "Yes"
     id: 1
1:Object
     name:"Anjie"
     Contact:"No"
     id: 2
2:Object
     name:"dillan"
     Contact:"Maybe"
     id:3
```

As you can see, i have added id and it auto increments whenever a new object is present.

Can someone let me know how to do this dynamically ?

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe consider using a for loop and iterating through the objects, assigning the iterator to each.

Comment: @JacobBuczarski- i can iterate. but i dont know how to insert the id in there and auto increment it for every object

Comment: I don't see a reason to tag angularjs.

Comment: @Patrick There's no auto-increment in Javascript. You should use another variable to hold the highest ID, and increment it.

Comment: If you create a for loop, you can assign iterator+1. If there are already ids in some of the values, you would need to find the highest, and use that val + (iterator+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually very simple. You can do it like this:

```js
var objs = [{
  name: "Rick",
  Contact: "Yes"
}, {
  name: "Anjie",
  Contact: "No"
}, {
  name: "dillan",
  Contact: "Maybe"
}];

objs.forEach(function(obj, index) {
  obj.id = index + 1;
});

console.log(objs);
```

For each object in the `objs` array, it adds an `id` with the value of the `index` (+1 because the index starts at 0)